# Change width of a card in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner to HTML and I'm making my first website.

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #39B59D, #139BDA, #0066FF, #061CFF);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.img {
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 500;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: #ffffff width=500;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p style="text-align:center;"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/nAaqJG/rappatic.png" alt="rappatic"></p>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="header">Hi, I'm rappatic.</h2>
    <p class="header">I code when I feel like it.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when it is run, the code shows a card that goes across almost the full width of the page. I think this is kind of ugly, though. Is there a way to make the card only stretch across, say, 50 or 60 percent of the page? Or, if that's not possible, make a set amount of pixels?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simpy missing the **unit** in the value of the width so you have to do this :

```
width: 500px;
```

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #39B59D, #139BDA, #0066FF, #061CFF);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.img {
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p style="text-align:center;"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/nAaqJG/rappatic.png" alt="rappatic"></p>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="header">Hi, I'm rappatic.</h2>
    <p class="header">I code when I feel like it.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want 50% you have to simply make it `width:50%` and you may add `margin:auto` for centering

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #39B59D, #139BDA, #0066FF, #061CFF);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.img {
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p style="text-align:center;"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/nAaqJG/rappatic.png" alt="rappatic"></p>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="header">Hi, I'm rappatic.</h2>
    <p class="header">I code when I feel like it.</p>
    <p>&nbsp</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Liked the `margin:auto` center thing. +1

Comment: @pagie_ you may also do `margin:20px auto` for example, the auto is uselful for left/right margin to center but do nothing for top/bottom, so you may specify values for these ;)

Comment: @pagie_ also pay attention to some syntax error, as you can see i removed `width=500` from container, as you should use `:` and not `=`

Answer (score 0):

for center this card use this code in your .card section:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the width of something, you can use the `width` property:

```
width: 500px;
width: 50%;
width: 50vw;
```

There are different units you can use, such as `px` (pixels) `%` (percentage of page width) and `vw` (percentage of window width).  There may also be others, but those are the ones I know of.